# Pine-Script - Input actual time as Default

Tags: time, pine-script

i´m trying to fill a Date input with a default value, the default value should be the actual date.

The original code:

`end_time = input.time(defval=timestamp('01 Aug 2021 00:00 +0000'), title='End Time')`

I would like to have the actual date as defval.

i tried several things, like timestamp(timenow) but i get always the same error-message:

> An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'const string' is expected

I understand that i bring a int to a string, but how can i convert the actual date/time to fit in the code above?

Thanx for your brains,

Answer (score 1):

The **input.*()** function **defval=** argument requires a value known at the compilation time and could not be dynamic.

As a workaround, you can use the interactive feature (**confirm=** argument) to select the last bar on the chart with a mouse-click:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
end_time = input.time(defval=timestamp('01 Aug 2021 00:00 +0000'), title='End Time', confirm = true)
bgcolor(time == end_time ? color.red : na)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was what i thought could be the problem. Is there a workaround to bring the Date into this argument at the start of the script? Like initiate the script, put the timestamp at the start into a const?

Comment: I don't think so, the available **bar_index**, **last_bar_index** and **timenow** are series and are not compatible with the input's **defval=**.